# Можно ли с помощью get запроса, через адресную строку, вытащить что либо из блока <div name='name_ar' contenteditable>$myrow[1]</div>

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, get

```
                $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','realestate');
            if (isset($_GET['id_ob_del'])) { 

                $id_del=$_GET['id_ob_del'];
                $sql = mysqli_query($c,'DELETE FROM arendator_ob WHERE id_ar='.$id_del);
            header("Location: create.php"); exit;

            }

            if (isset($_POST['red'])){
            if (isset($_GET['id_ob_red'])) { 
            echo    $name_ar=$_POST['name_ar'];
            echo    $fam_ar=$_POST['fam_ar'];
            echo    $telefon_ar=$_POST['telefon_ar'];
            echo    $pasport_ar=$_POST['pasport_ar'];
            echo    $id_del=$_GET['id_ob_del'];
                $sql = mysqli_query($c,"UPDATE arendator_ob 
                SET id_ar='$id_del',name_ar='$name_ar',fam_ar='$fam_ar',telefon_ar='$telefon_ar',pasport_ar='$pasport_ar'
                WHERE id_ar=".$id_del); 
            header("Location: create.php"); exit;

            }
            }

            $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','realestate');
            $q=mysqli_query($c,'select * from arendator_ob ');
            echo "<form action='create.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<thead >";
            echo "<tr><th>№</th><th>Имя</td><th>Фамилия</th><th>Телефон</th><th>Паспорт</th></tr>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<form>";
            while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
            echo "<tr><th><div>$myrow[0]</div></th><th><div name='name_ar' contenteditable>$myrow[1]</div></th><th><div name='fam_ar' contenteditable>$myrow[2]</div></th><th>";
            echo "<div name='telefon_ar' contenteditable>$myrow[3]</div></th><th><div name='pasport_ar' contenteditable>$myrow[4]</div></th><th><a href='create.php?id_ob_red=$myrow[0]''>Изменить</a></th>";
            echo "<th><a name='red' href='create.php?id_ob_del=$myrow[0]''>Удалить</a></th></tr>";
                  }


                echo "</table>";
                echo "</form>";
```

Пытаюсь запрограммировать кнопку Изменить в таблице извлекаемой из бд, тем же способом что и сделал удаление. Не знаю возможно ли вообще так сделать,но сейчас я не могу передать даже данные из блоков div способом который придумал сам.
Я пытаюсь избежать использование тега input (дивом красивее[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: Про табуляцию и sql инъекции я знаю, прошу простить за мою некомпетентность.

Comment: Код надо вставлять сюда __текстом__.

Comment: жесть...и да...не совсем ясно что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Я хочу извлечь текст из div и далее отправить этот текст  запросом update в таблицу в базе данных

Comment: с помощью js извлекаете div и отправляете на сервер (я думаю что то на подобии `ajax` вам подойдет) и на сервере обрабатываете ( шлете запрос в бд)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а средствами php нельзя?

Comment: php - серверный язык....а div находится на клиенте